# Yii 2 - GridView doesn't fix in the screen. How to fix it?

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2

I have this problem: The GridView I has in the view (shown below) is too long that it doesn't fit entirely in the screen, maybe because one value parameter is too long, and it doesn't follow the text down. This this a screenshot for the GridView:

[image]

And this the code for the GridView

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'fecha',
            'nombreSesion',
            'objetivosPlanificacion:ntext',


            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); 
    ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is problem of CSS

look in /web/css/site.css and search

```
.grid-view td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and change it to

```
.grid-view td {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can trim values when you fetch it in gridview as below

**Instead of**

'objetivosPlanificacion:ntext',

**Use**

```
[
 'attribute' => 'objetivosPlanificacion',
 'value' => function($dataProvider){
    return trim($dataProvider->objetivosPlanificacion, ' ');
 }
],
```

Things shall work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not showing the full value of the attribute `objetivosPlanificacion` you can do the following:

```
use yii\helpers\StringHelper;
...
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'fecha',
            'nombreSesion',
            [
                'attribute' => 'objetivosPlanificacion',
                'value' => function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return StringHelper::truncate($model->objetivosPlanificacion, 50);
                },
                'format' => 'ntext',
            ],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); 
    ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Basically truncate the attribute value and format is as ntext.